# How to atomically write 128MB to a file?

Tags: c++, file

I need to put continuous block of variable size 16...128 MB to a file with no risk of leaving file structure in inconsistent state (in case of power failure or process death).

By the **consistent state** of the file I mean the guarantee that the old data is available and any space, consumed by failed writes can be re-used. In other words, every piece of file must be distinguishable between categories "good data" and "garbage" at any moment of time despite of any software write failures (we assume the disk unit is OK).

What simplest data structure in the file and what algorithm could one propose to provide that?

Related question: how a DBMS (the ones working on top of filesystem (MySQL InnoDB, MongoDB, Redis etc), not the ones on top of raw HDD (Oracle)) deal with the similar issues?

Comment: This depends on the operating system and/or underlying filesystem: and you may end up having an answer that is simply "you can't", or "it's not easy"

Comment: Write it to a temp file and rename it at the end to overwrite the previous file.

Comment: All [journaling file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) have that feature built in. You don't have to do anything, if you are using a journaling file system.

Comment: Please ask the real question already. This is the second time you ask about potentially unrelated information. What problem are you ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: @iinspectable no, the JFS will not put my `write(fd, buff, 128*1024*1024)` to a journal. It is unable "write entire 128MB or write nothing".

Comment: That's not what you were asking for either (*"every piece of file must be distinguishable between categories 'good data' and 'garbage'"*). A JFS guarantees that. But that's completely besides the point. What are you **really** trying to accomplish?

Comment: @iinspectable the real problem is... The 16...128MB of data arrived and must be saved with no risk in future garbage reads.

Comment: You'll need a transactional filesystem for that (e.g. [Transactional NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS)).

Comment: @iinspectable no, the JFS can't provide "all or nothing" for the "write 128MB" operation issued in userspace.

Comment: Again, that's not what you are asking for in your question. I answered the question you asked, not the question you meant to ask.

Comment: Hash the data, write the hash to disk, flush the disk, ensure the hash is there properly, then write that data. You can then check the data against the hash to see if it matches in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of different approaches, depending on whether you need to overwrite or append.

## Overwriting

If you want to overwrite, do as has been suggested in the comments. Write your content out to a temp file, then copy the temp file over the original. If the temp file is present at the start of the write, you'll know something went wrong and you should discard it. If it's not, you can proceed normally.

## Appending

This one's trickier. What you can do before writing is append a string to the file that won't appear in your content. Anything after that string is considered "suspect" until the string is deleted (which is done at the end of the write). Again, if you begin to write and discover the string in your file, you can delete it and anything after it as being suspect. If you don't encounter it, you can write it and your content as normal.

Comment: That's an insanely naïve way to think about atomicity. What if your guard string is written halfway through, when the power fails? There's no way of telling, which part of the file holds valid contents anymore. No, this simply won't work like this. Likewise, the copy method is broken for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

This will be os dependent. But in general you will need to use unbuffered IO to write to the end of the file. Once that succeeds update some type of header information that indicates the new record is complete.  You could combine that with a temp file swap for extra reliability.